# Click on text to produce a sheet output

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have the following code that produces a block for me, with two hyperlinks:

```
HStack(alignment: .center) {
    Text("By signing up, you agree to our [Terms of Service](https://example.com) and our [Privacy Policy](https://example.com).")
        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Regular", size: 12))
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
}
```

That gives me the following:

[image]

Is there anyway that I can make the "Terms of Service" and "Privacy Policy" open a sheet using:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showTermsofService)
      showTermsofService() <-- View

.sheet(isPresented: $showPrivacyPolicy)
      showPrivacyPolicy() <-- View
```

All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever wonders how to answer this, here is the code that works:

```
VStack {
    Text("By signing up, you agree to our [Terms of Service](terms-of-service) and our [Privacy Policy](privacy-policy).")
        .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Regular", size: 12))
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
            switch url.absoluteString {
            case "terms-of-service":
                showTermsofServiceSheet = true
                return .handled
            case "privacy-policy":
                showPrivacyPolicySheet = true
                return .handled
            default:
                return .discarded
            }
        })
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showTermsofServiceSheet) {
    TermsofServiceView()
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showPrivacyPolicySheet) {
    PrivacyPolicyView()
}
.padding(.horizontal, 30)
```